# Turbulence in Statistical Mechanics approach

Tags: fluid-dynamics, statistical-mechanics, turbulence, partition-function

Is it feasible to describe Turbulence (at continuum scale) using Statistical mechanics approach?

For example, Is it reasonable to model a turbulent round jet at an instant time in space as a $N,V,T$ system with partition function $Q = q^{N}/{N!}$ trying to optimize its free energy?

Where $N$, represents the number of indistinguishable, interacting fluid bulks, $q$ is particle function of single fluid bulk. Fluid bulks can be assumed to act like hard-spheres where the interaction of particles within the bulk is negligible compared to interaction between bulks.

Comment: Only equilibrium systems optimize their free energy

Comment: See [Extremal principles in non-equilibrium thermodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremal_principles_in_non-equilibrium_thermodynamics)

Comment: I would argue that "turbulent at an instant [of] time" is non-nonsensical. By definition turbulence is transient.

Comment: A quick [Google research](https://www.google.fr/search?q=turbulence+statistical+mechanics&ie=utf-8) gives you a pretty good idea of the feasibility of a statistical mechanics approach to turbulent flows. You can even make [a book](http://www.springer.com/la/book/9783540401032) about it. But your question seems legit, even [Robert Kraichnan and Shiyi Chen](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0167278989901267) asked it. (I am not a specialist of statistical mechanics so I can't really answer the question.)